# ArcMap won't export USGSTopo basemap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, basemap, arcgis-online-basemaps

On Friday we started switching the basemaps on some preexisting maps to the `USGSTopo` basemap provided by ESRI through ArcMap (10.8.2). This was working fine with no issues. Suddenly starting Monday, every time a map is exported with the `USGSTopo` map, the basemap isn't exported.

Few things:

- This ONLY happens with the `USGSTopo` basemap, all other basemaps through ESRI seem to export with no problems.
- The `USGSTopo` basemap WILL export if the map zoom is 1:10,0000 to 1:24,000
- The `USGSTopo` basemap WILL export if the DPI is set to 50 or lower.
- Exporting as a TIF (or other image file) also only works if the DPI
  is below 50.
- Maps that were exporting fine on Friday, also no longer export
  correctly.

I've been trying solutions online for the past day and have yet to get anywhere. It seems like an obvious resolution problem, but I can't understand why it only is affecting this one basemap, and why the resolution needs to be obliterated for it to process.

Comment: There are some WMS and ArcGIS server basemaps that will restrict the number of pixels it will provide for any request; these are enough to display properly on the computer but not enough for export to a large and/or high enough quality export.  It's also possible the site is just having some temporary limitations.  You don't indicate your server source but here's two USGS topo sources and one might work better than the other: http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer
https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryTopo/MapServer

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Export at a lower dpi. Mine works at up to 200 which is enough to be acceptable. They seem to have changed the level of resolution you're able to export in this specific Basemap only. I could export at 1000 dpi before the holidays but now only up to 200. Would have been nice to have known this change was happening.